# How to make an ImageView overflows to the Toolbar in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I have a Toolbar and some fragments in FrameLayout. However in such a case I am asked to make an ImageView in a fragment which its half will be on the Toolbar. I couldn't figure it out. I considered to cut the image and make it an Options menu item and rest of it will be on the top of the fragment, but I think this won't be very effective for different devices. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure what exactly u need.
But if I get it. Here is something u can do.
U just need to make your fragment on whole screen and draw toolbar over fragment.

Here is the snippet. I don't tested it:

**your_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <Toolbar //name possibly incorrect(change to correct one)
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then inside fragment layout:

**fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView //or any other container for your stuff
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:clipToPadding="false"/>

    <ImageView //your imageView that will draw halfover toolbar
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/half_toolbar_height"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

The snippet above possibly won't work correctly. But anyway it can be start point to solve your problem. Good luck!